# jQuery - reset slice() for the next element

Tags: jquery, reset, slice

I've got some tables. They all have the same class, they're all generated by the same code. I'd like to only show three rows of each table by hiding the rest of the rows using jQuery. Later on I'll add a link to allow the user to expand a given table, but for now I'd like to just hide the later elements.

I'm doing this with slice(), but I notice that slice() does not reset its index when it moves on to the next table. I'm probably doing something wrong in my jQuery selector.

Here's the JSFiddle, I'll include the HTML and JS on this post anyway just in case.
http://jsfiddle.net/3pf3z/1/

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".booking tr" ).slice(3).hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="booking">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>

<br /><br />

<table class="booking">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There were three good answers for this question. One stood out for pointing me to each().

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the accept. Helps us improve future answers =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `each()`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".booking" ).each(function() {
       $(this).find("tr").slice(3).hide();
    });
});
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/efWpN/1/

jQuery [docs on each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Thank you, that's spot on! I didn't know about each(), so the jQuery docs link provided good reading.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(".booking").each(function(){
    $(this).find('tr:lt(3)').hide();   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3pf3z/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".booking" ).each(function(){
    $(this).find("tr").slice(3).hide();
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3pf3z/3/